# Why does list.__iadd__ work with other iterable object types when __add__ does not?

Tags: python-3.x

I recently came across a python FIFO buffer [example](https://github.com/ArduPilot/pymavlink/blob/f55377066e5f5dba2c63b7a5d116454b1b0ce303/examples/mavtest.py#L13-L20), which initialized the buffer as an empty list despite the intended input and output being of type `bytes` or `bytearray`.  To my surprise this was not a mistake, and I have been left stumped as to why `list.__iadd__` works in this case, but not `list.__add__`.

Below is code demonstrating this discrepancy (python version 3.7.4).

```py
>>> buffer = []
>>> some_bytes = b'12345'
>>> some_bytearray = bytearray(some_bytes)
>>> buffer + some_bytes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "bytes") to list
>>> buffer += some_bytes
>>> buffer
[49, 50, 51, 52, 53]
>>> buffer + some_bytearray
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "bytearray") to list
>>> buffer += some_bytearray
>>> buffer
[49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53]
```

Edit: this same functionality also applies to other iterate types such as `str`, `dict` and `tuple`.  Does `__iadd__` attempt to mutate the argument if `__add__` raises a `TypeError`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List concatenation (adding) requires that both variables in the operation are lists - this (I guess) allows us to be sure of the type of object that will result from the operation.  Otherwise we predict cannot the type of object that resulted from

```
some_list + some_set
```

On the other hand, extending the a list (`somelist += ...`) only requires that the object on the right hand side be an *iterable*, so that each of its elements can be added to the original list.

```
>>> L = []
>>> L += {1, 2, 3}
>>> L
[1, 2, 3]
>>> L += ('a', 'b', 'c')
>>> L
[1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c']
>>> L += ['x', 'y', 'z']
>>> L
[1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

In short, concatenation returns a *new object*, so the left and right and sides of the expression need to be of the same *type*.  In-place addition *mutates the original object*, so the object on the left hand side need only be an iterable, its type is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

The answer appears to be in:

```
a = bytearray()
help(a)
....
|  __add__(self, value, /)
|      Return self+value.
...
|  __iadd__(self, value, /)
|      Implement self+=value.
...
```

Thus, `iadd` changes the class while `add` does not.

Comment: Does `Implement` imply that the class is altered in some way?  If so is there a more detailed way of understanding exactly what happens here?

Comment: @CampbellMcDiarmid Yes, we are not creating a new class with the elements with `iadd`. `iadd` will process the items differently than if we were to create a new class with "return" and `add`.